# Catch error when QList index is out of bounds

Tags: c++, cascade, blackberry-10

I am developing an application for BlackBerry 10 and when I try to get the element 2 from a QStringList while this list contains only one element, my application crashes.

I am using the following code to catch this type of error:

```
try {
    // A code that accesses QStringList with an index out of bounds
}
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

But the exception is not caught and the application always crashes.

I tried catch (std:exception& e) and catch(...), and it didn't work either.

How can I use the try catch to catch this error?

Comment: I think you want to catch `const std::exception& e`.

Comment: @BoBTFish This is not catching the error. I tried it previously before posting the question

Comment: Well what is the actual type of the exception being thrown? On second thoughts it is probably not a `std::exception`. So most likely it inherits from some other exception base class.

Comment: I think I get the situation now. When you dereference a null pointer, you don't get an exception. You get undefined behaviour. Most likely a crash. This is not an exception, so you can't catch it like one. (I think windows generates something that it calls an exception, but isn't really the same thing. No clue what would happen on a Blackberry).

Comment: @BoBTFish I think you've nailed it. Qt especially doesn't really work well with exceptions, so I can't imagine `QStringList` throwing one instead of simply doing UB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accessing a `QList` out of its range **doesn't throw an exception**. Instead, it **assumes** that you already checked that the index is in the range (what happens if this isn't true is explained below).

Actually, this is not a bad design but a good design of the container class: Sometimes (in most of the cases) you already know that indices are in the range. If Qt should react to out-of-bound accesses by throwing exceptions, this means you want to rely on this check, which means this check *has* to be done (even if you don't need Qt to check it). What Qt does instead is to assume you provide a valid index. In debug builds, this gets checked with an **assertion** and if the assertion isn't met your program terminates *with a reason* (you can track it nicely for debugging), but in release mode this **check isn't done at all**, so it silently produces undefined behavior if the index was out of bounds by *still* accessing the raw memory in the data structure. This is as fast as possible, but requires the index to be valid.

Assertions will terminate your process if they aren't met, meaning you can't "catch" this kind of error. **Avoid it in the first place**, i.e. test for your index being in range *before* accessing the list.

Note that some (maybe all?) container classes also provide an access with a "real" index check (no crash, also in a release build), i.e. with defined and intended behavior when it is out of bounds. For `QList`, this function is:

```
T value(int index, T fallbackValue)
```

It tries to access the element at `index` with a bounds check. If your index is not in range (or in associative containers: it was not found), the `fallbackValue` you have given will be returned. The second parameter defaults to a default-constructed `T`. Note that this value has to be constructed even if your index is correct. This is why even in cases where you want the check it might be better to do the check manually with a branch, and only construct a default value if needed (in particular if you need to evaluate an expensive expression to construct your fallback value):

```
if (index < myList.count())   // We only check upper bound in this scenario
    foo = myList[index];
else
    foo = expensiveFunctionReturningMyFallbackValue();
```

Comment: Are you sure it asserts? Looking at the documentation for [`QList::at`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#at) and [`QList::operator[]`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d), they both say `i must be a valid index position in the list (i.e., 0 <= i < size()).`. Haven't checked the exact meaning of this wording they use, but it certainly implies to me it doesn't do any kind of check whatsoever.

Comment: @BoBTFish debug build: `assert`,  release build: "assume"

Answer (score -1):

I am not programming on BlackBerry, but if the exception was not caught, the most possible reason is that the type the exception you throw is not Exception. As the last resort, you may try to catch all.

```
try {
    //a code that throws Null Pointer Exception
}
catch (...) {
}
```

And you should use const reference to avoid unwanted side effects.

Comment: how to catch all? you mean catch(...)? Because it didn't work

Comment: You just posted his code snippet exactly? Did you mean to change it to `catch (...)`? Which should work, but is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry, I means catch(...) indeed.